# Arrow-kt: how to turn an Either<E, List<Either<E,A>>> into Either<E, List<B>>

Tags: list, transform, flatten, either, arrow-kt

I receive an `Either<E, List<A>>` from a function call and need to transform the `List<A>` into a `List<B>`. The transformation of each A returns an `Either<E,B>`, so that my result is an `Either<E, List<Either<E,B>>>`. How can I turn the `Either<E, List<Either<E,B>>>` into an `Either<E, List<B>>`,

- if all transformation succeeded (Should result in `Either.Left`, if a single transformation fails)
- create an `Either<E,List<B>>` containing all Bs, for which the transformation succeeded and ignoring failed AtoB transformations

A little code snippet below:

```
fun getListOfA(): Either<Exception, List<A>> {
    TODO()
}

fun A.transformAtoB(): Either<Exception, B> {
    TODO()
}


fun getListB(): Either<Exception, List<B>> {
    return getListOfA().map {

        // this is now Either<Exception, List<Either<Exception, B>>>
        listOfA -> listOfA.map { it.transformAtoB() }

        // ????? => Either<E, List<B>>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function called `traverseEither` that allows you to do these kind of operations.

`public inline fun <E, A, B> Iterable<A>.traverseEither(f: (A) -> Either<E, B>): Either<E, List<B>>`

For every value of `A` in the `Iterable` it will call `f`, and if all the results are `Either.Right` then it will result in `Either.Right<List<B>>` and otherwise it will result in the first `Either.Left<E>` it encounters.

So we can rewrite your snippet:

```kotlin
fun getListOfA(): Either<Exception, List<A>> = TODO()

fun A.transformAtoB(): Either<Exception, B> = TODO()

fun getListB(): Either<Exception, List<B>> =
    getListOfA().flatMap { listOfA ->

        // this is now Either<Exception, List<Either<Exception, B>>>
        listOfA.traverseEither { it.transformAtoB() }
    }
```

It also exists for `Validated`, `Option` etc https://arrow-kt.io/docs/apidocs/arrow-core/arrow.core/kotlin.collections.-iterable/index.html#extensions-for-kotlincollectionsiterable

And you can also find parallel variants inside Arrow Fx Coroutines

Comment: .map{} needs to be changed to .flatMap{} to get Either<E, List<B>>. But otherwise this is the solution I was looking for!

Comment: If the transformation would return an Option<B> instead of an Either, such as in A.transformToB():Option<B>, how could this be traversed?

Comment: There is also `traverseOption`, and `traverseValidated`, etc. You can find them all in the link shared in the post.

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not see any traverseOption(). I read the linked page before, but there is also no traverseOption in the description. There is a traverse(), traverseEither() and traverseValidated(). On a List<A> I can only do traverseEither/traverseValidated. Am I missing to include another library here? I can apply filterOption() to a List<Option<B>> which does kind of the same, ignoring all None's. But if I want to fail on Nones, seemingly the only available option is to turn the Option into an Either and then apply traverseEither()

Comment: My apologies, `traverseOption` is only added since `0.13.3` & `1.0.0` which is to be released September 2021 (later this week of writing).